# Switch Focus Windows Different Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, focus, webdriver

I've been working on a scenario for Selenium WebDriver

I had been successfully create two webdriver to run concurrently.
The problem I face now is how to switch between these two windows.

I tried `driver.switchTo().window()` but no luck since it could only work for windows generated in one driver.

I had these two drivers:

`firstDriver` and `secondDriver` to be used in PageFactory

Any idea how to switch focus between two windows generated by different webdriver?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to put a browser from background to front?

Answer (score 0):

Two WebDriver are two separated browsers. You can't switch between their window.
When you want use other browser (driver) use them separately.

example:

`firstDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div")).getText();
secondDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div")).getText();`

First line return you string from div in first browser, second line from second browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I want is just like when the firstDriver is doing its work, the focus is set to the windows generated by the firstDriver and also the same for the secondDriver. Is it possible? @Son ?

Comment: What do you mean "the focus is set to the windows generated by the firstDriver"?
Do you want to see what that browser does on screen?

Comment: You have 2 options for that:
minimalize and maximalize browser, or using robot do Alt+Tab :)
But why you want do that? You can use webdriver without having "visual focus" on that.

Comment: :) I was sort of figure out that would be the answer. Yes, it isnt neccessary actually, just try to make it looks nicer tho :p